# in phpMyAdmin - Removal of the 'more settings' option

Tags: phpmyadmin, settings

I have been working on trying to hide the option for a user to have access to the pma configuration settings.  I have so far commented out the following section of code in prefs_manage.php

[code]

```
/*
if (file_exists('setup/index.php')) {
            // show only if setup script is available, allows to disable this message
            // by simply removing setup directory
            ?>
            <div class="group">
            <h2><?php echo __('More settings') ?></h2>
            <div class="group-cnt">
                <?php
                echo sprintf(
                    __(
                        'You can set more settings by modifying config.inc.php, eg. '
                        . 'by using %sSetup script%s.'
                    ), '<a href="setup/index.php" target="_blank">', '</a>'
                ) . PMA_Util::showDocu('setup', 'setup-script');
                ?>
            </div>
            </div>
        <?php
}
        ?>
    </div>*/
```

Here is a quick photo of the setting im trying to hide/disable for other users.  Thanks so much!

https://whatimg.com/i/brOhrv.png

Comment: To provide just a little more information , when it is commented out, although the link: 'More Settings' is visible, when it is clicked the result is an internal server error, which i suppose serves the purpose, but i wanted to clean it up  a little bit or just remove that option all together.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this in the code of index.php

You can simply remove it or comment it out

```
// User preferences
/*
if ($server > 0) {
    echo '<ul>';
    PMA_printListItem(
        PMA_Util::getImage('b_tblops.png') . " " . __('More settings'),
        'li_user_preferences',
        'prefs_manage.php' . $common_url_query,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        "no_bullets"
    );
    echo '</ul>';
}

echo '</div>';


echo '</div>';
*/
```